# Obtain raw data size aiohttp.ClientSession

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

Are any way to obtain raw data size sent\received through aiohttp.ClientSession?

Comment: The answer depends on what you need.
What is your use case?

Comment: I'd like to get full size of the sent \ received data for my mobile application using aiohttp

Comment: With or without headers? Do you count service information like HTTP chunk length encoding?

Comment: With headers. Now i use ClientResponse.content.total_bytes. But this variable contains only payload size value without headers. I use aiohttp for restapi, so the payload size is very often less than the headers size, which means incorrect statistics.

Comment: Sorry, aiohttp has no such functionality. Moreover I afraid a counting for all data is in the library scope.

Comment: Ok. I look at "aiohttp/http_writer.py". There is "on_chunk_sent" callback at "write" function. It will be fine if the same calback "on_headers_sent" just will be implemented for "write_headers" function. And same for receive events.

Comment: Don't see how it can help but you can create an issue for discussion